# Is there a way to replant papyrus after the winter?

Tags: seeds, overwintering, replant

I live in growing region 6a, at very high altitude, in a low-precipitation area, with random snowfall and freezes happening until June 1, but freezes being mild (around 15 degrees F) and short-lasting. Experience gardeners (which I am not) claim it is difficult to grow in this area. Nearly everything I planted failed or wilted. The one plant that has grown successful has been papyrus (*Cyperus percamenthus*), which have grown to 4 ft tall. They are grown in the shallow region of a pond, fertilized by goldfish. As such, I want to grow more.

It is difficult to purchase these plants in my area, but next spring, I'd expand from growing just 2 of these to 50-100 plants (as many as is possible). That would cost upwards of $1000 if I purchased the plants, not to mention the supply just isn't available, so I want to try to replant from these two that I have.

I read they likely won't regrow after winter. I can't find anything resembling seeds on these plants. Is there some part I can harvest or cut, keep over the winter, and replant in June, so that I can have a multitude of these plants next year?

Answer (score 2):

In zone 8 Cyprus papyrus, will die back to some degree each winter depending on temperature. But it always comes back vigorously and is invasive here. Acorus is a more cold hardy bog plant . It is very easy ( aka invasive) here; if you want something to try. Acorus is often variegated color and gets about one foot tall.

Comment: Do I understand right, zone 8 has winters that aren't as cold as zone 6? So if it does well in zone 8, it might not do so well in zone 6?

Comment: Yes : References on the net generally list zones where it will never die back ( zone 9). One site did imply that if the underground rhizome does not freeze , it will come back in spring; that is what happens here in zone 8. I think it has a good chance of coming back in zone 6 if the rhizome does not freeze. Alternatively the rhizomes could be dug up and stored in a cool ,damp place during freezing weather.